# Scrapy specify default shell for `scrapy shell`

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

According to its docs, Scrapy will use ipython if it has been installed in the user's system. Is it possible to have ipython installed but still direct Scrapy to use the default python shell by specifying the `shell` field in `scrapy.cfg`?

Currently, no matter what I specify in that field, Scrapy is using ipython (even if it is omitted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the scrapy documentation:

> Through Scrapy’s settings you can configure it to use any one of ipython, bpython or the standard python shell, regardless of which are installed. This is done by setting the SCRAPY_PYTHON_SHELL environment variable; or by defining it in your scrapy.cfg:

The default `scrapy.cfg` looks like this:

```
# Automatically created by: scrapy startproject
#
# For more information about the [deploy] section see:
# https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy.html

[settings]
default = projectname.settings


[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = projectname
```

So in order to specify which shell to use you need to add it under the `settings` header, like this.

```
# Automatically created by: scrapy startproject
#
# For more information about the [deploy] section see:
# https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy.html

[settings]
default = projectname.settings
shell = python

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = projectname
```

I have tested and confirmed that this works and does use the standard python shell even when I have ipython installed in the same environment.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I was in a parent directory of `scrapy.cfg` when running `scrapy shell`, so it was defaulting to ipython as a result!